# JQuery two column image slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I have been looking for a two column Jquery slider (in which image is on the left and clickable image title is on the right) for past few hours. I am unable to find anything even remotely close. I don't even know if it is called Two column slider.

Here is what I am looking for: 
[image]

Any help (slider name, suggestion) anything at all would be highly appreciated

Ahmar

Comment: best option write your own according to your needs

Comment: @fr34k I am not an expert at all in Jquery

Comment: @Ahmar Ali try this http://www.jssor.com/demos/tab-slider.html

Comment: Why not view the source of the site in your screenshot and see what they used? It's JavaScript, so it will be visible.

Comment: @dartonw it is a image not html code :p